# jquery simple pager with first , last

Tags: php, jquery, pager

```
<code>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>jQuery.pager.js Test</title>
    <link href="Pager.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="jquery-1.2.6.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery.pager.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#pager").pager({ pagenumber: 1, pagecount: 15, buttonClickCallback: PageClick });
        });

        PageClick = function(pageclickednumber) {
            $("#pager").pager({ pagenumber: pageclickednumber, pagecount: 15, buttonClickCallback: PageClick });
            $("#result").html("Clicked Page " + pageclickednumber);
        }

    </script>

</head>
<body>

$query = "select name from student";
$result = mysql_query(Query);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$student_name = $row['name'];
?>
<h1 id="result"><?php echo $student_name; ?></h1>
<? }
?>

<div id="pager" />
</body>
</html>
</code>
```

For my above code am not geting the student name , if i remove the pager script , the student name will appear, may i know , why, where i made mistake..

i thing i have to pass somthing to html()  , but i am not sure..

Comment: @Bharanikumar - to format your code, you can highlight it and press on the button that looks like a bunch of *binary numbers* at the top of the text area.

Comment: sorry , how to highlight,tell me plz
i have to use <pre> or <code> is there any thing else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){ $student_name = $row['name']; }
```

should be

```
$student_name = NULL;
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){ $student_name .= $row['name']; }
```